# New to lisp. I was wondering why I get this error. "1 is not of type LIST."

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun fizzbuzz(lst emptyList)
    (if (= (mod (car lst) 3) 0)
    (fizzbuzz (cdr lst) (append emptyList (list(append (car lst) '(fizz)))))
    )
    (if (= (mod (car lst) 5) 0)
    (fizzbuzz (cdr lst) (append emptyList (list(append (car lst) '(buzz)))))
    )
    (if (and (= (mod (car lst) 3) 0) (= (mod (car lst) 5) 0))
    (fizzbuzz (cdr lst) (append emptyList (list(append (car lst) 
    '(fizzbuzz)))))
    )
    (fizzbuzz (cdr lst) (append emptyList (car lst)))
```

)

```
(fizzbuzz '(1 2 3 4 5) '(0))
```

Keep in mind I am new. My professor wants us to practice recursion using lisp. The program is supposed to add numbers that arent divisible by 5 or 3 to a list.
Those that are divisible by 3 get inserted into the list like so (3 fizz). Those divisible by 5: (5 buzz). Those divisible by both (15 fizzbuzz). How would I return the new list from the function? Also why am I getting the error listed in the title of the post?

Comment: Maybe you should check which type of arguments APPEND expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because of the last expression `(fizzbuzz (cdr lst) (append emptyList (car lst)))`.

First round `(fizzbuzz '(1 2 3 4 5) '(0))` becomes `(fizzbuzz '(2 3 4 5) '(0 . 1))` and then it will try to do `(append '(0 . 1) 2)`. `append` can handle dotted list and atom as last argument, but it cannot append a dotted list when not the last argument. What is it supposed to do with the `1`?

Also know that you have no stop condition and the separate `if` is run unconditionally to the other `if` so for `15` it will first recurse in the first, then throw away that result. Then it will recurse in the second to just throw that value away as well. Then unconditionally it will recurse in the last. I'm pretty sure you would only want one of them to be called and you do that with `if-elseif-else` and the lisp version of that is `cond`:

```
(cond 
  (p1 c1)      ; if p1 then c1
  (p2 c2 c2b)  ; elseif p2 then c2 and c2b (last expression becomes the result)
  (p3 c3)      ; elseif p3 then c3
  (t  a4))     ; else a4
```

Comment: (fizzbuzz (cdr lst) (append emptyList (list (append (list(car lst)) '(buzz)))))

Comment: Now the append works but I will try the other things you have suggested.

Comment: I am confused about the syntax. I don't have to write "if" after "cond" right?

Comment: (defun condTest(item)
  (cond (and (= (mod (car lst) 3) 0) (= (mod (car lst) 5) 0)))
   (=(mod item 3) 0 (princ "fizz"))
   (=(mod item 5) 0 (princ "buzz"))))

Comment: @AaronLoomis you need the paretheses. eg. `(cond ((null lst) (nreverse acc)) ((= (mod (car lst) 15) 0) (fizzbuzz (cdr lst) (cons "fizzbuzz" acc))) ...)` Here I assume the second arhument is called `acc` and I'm adding element to the front of it and reverse it when I'm done. It's faster than recreating the list at every iteration like you need to do with `append`.

Comment: Or you can nest ifs `(if p1 c1 (if p2 (progn c2 c2b) (if p3 c3 a4)))`. That is the same as the `cond` in my answer and as you can see `cond` is easier to read since it makes for a flatter structure. Actually if you `macroexpand` a cond clause you get nested ifs.